# Wondering about iMessage security over work WiFi?

Tags: wifi

I work for a very large, tech heavy organization and I use WiFi at work - been there for many years and have been using their WiFi the whole time. I also use iMessage almost exclusively and I’m starting to wonder about general security of my messages while on their WiFi, are my messages actually private? If an employer wanted to go through the messages sent, would they just require a cell number to be able to pick out my information?

I don’t use a work issued cell and I’ve never given it to them for any programs to be downloaded onto it. I’d like to believe that private messages sent to my spouse, job hunting inquires, etc... would be private because I’m using iMessage, but is that really the case?

What other information would they be able to get? Is there an expectation of privacy that is legally enforceable? I would almost understand messages sent for work purposes being monitored, but outside of those specific contacts, could they access private transmissions as well?

I’ve used their WiFi for a long time, I can’t remember if I ever gave a special security certificates a long time ago or how I could even check that?

Comment: This site is about 3D printing. Have you posted on the wrong site by mistake? I see you also have an account on [security.se] but you haven't asked the question there.

Comment: Oops! Yep, wrong forum! Sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work cannot intercept your messages. Further, iMessage messages are end-to-end encrypted which means that *not even Apple* can intercept your messages without making substantial, obvious software updates which would tip off many security researches. The only circumstances in which your employer could see your messages is if they installed a custom app on your phone which made use of private APIs. Since you stated in your question that they have not installed any software on your phone, you are in the clear.

[See page 60 of this Apple provided PDF for a more in-depth, technical overview of how iMessage security works.](https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf)